# Equivalence of discrete metric and euclidean

Tags: calculus, general-topology

Is there any example of set which is open in a metric space with discrete metric and not open in that space with the Euclidean topology?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any set $A\subset \Bbb R^n$ which is not open in the topology induced by the Euclidian metric is open in the topology induced by the discrete metric, because every subset is open in the discrete topology.

Comment: To make it concrete, $A = \Bbb Q^n$ is an example.